# Can't connect to MySQL databse of any webhost from anywhere other than the webhost itself

Tags: mysql, database, web-services, web-hosting

I have 2 different webhost (`pagodabox` & `000webhost`, both free) and I've set up a `localhost` with MySQL.

I've installed wordpress on all three of them which work perfectly fine within their own domain -- ie. when `localhost` wordpress is using `localhost` database, `pagodabox` is using `pagodabox` database and so on.

However if I change database access credentials from `wp-config.php` in order to, say, make `localhost` wordpress connect to `000webhost` database, it doesn't work: **`"Error establishing database"`**.

Here's the respective credentials I use:

```
<?php

wp-config.php - relevant differences

* members.000webhost.com/panel/Manage MySQL Databases    
    // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //    
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */    
    define('DB_NAME', '--------_db');    
    /** MySQL database username */    
    define('DB_USER', '--------');    
    /** MySQL database password */    
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '--------');    
    /** MySQL hostname */    
    define('DB_HOST', 'mysq--.000webhost.com');    

* tunnel.pagodabox.com
    // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //    
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */    
    define('DB_NAME', '--------_db');    
    /** MySQL database username */    
    define('DB_USER', '--------');    
    /** MySQL database password */    
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '--------');    
    /** MySQL hostname */    
    define('DB_HOST', 'tunnel.pagodabox.com');    

* localhost    
    // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //    
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */    
    define('DB_NAME', '--------_db');    
    /** MySQL database username */    
    define('DB_USER', '--------');    
    /** MySQL database password */    
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '--------');    
    /** MySQL hostname */    
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');    

?>
```

Comment: You can bet they have this locked down. After all, you get what you pay for. If you want this kind of flexibility you're gonna have to pay for hosting that supports it.

Comment: Most free, and many paid webhosts only allow internal access to MySql. Dreamhosters supports outide access via a whitelist, 1and1 doesn't support external access.  Just my own experiences.

Comment: Can you access your `localhost` MySQL from the internet? If so, try making the wordpress on the other hosts use your `localhost` MySQL. If this works, you can be sure that their servers forbid access from outside their network. Also, you can try to `telnet` them to see if they have the 3306 port open to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have cPanel, and "Remote MySQL" is enabled in your cPanel, then..

> You can allow external web servers to access your MySQL databases by adding their domain name to the list of hosts that are able to access databases on your web site.

[image: Remote MySQL in cPanel]

However I guess you are trying to connect to 000webhost from your local computer. I don't think you can do that because cPanel won't consider it a valid host.

Comment: However I guess you are trying to connect to 000webhost from your local computer. I don't think you can do that because cPanel won't consider it a valid host

this comment is very helpful Thank u 
we can use hostname as localhost in server